# Updating records one by one

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have 5000 records I am calculating salary of one user and update his data in database. So it’s taking quit long to update 5000 records. I want to calculate all users’ salary first and then update to records in db.
 Is there any other way we can update db in single click

Comment: Please be more specific..what you mean by "calculate salary of 5000 one by one" ?

Comment: It would helpf if you would also tell us how do you calculate the salary.

Comment: more details needed about your problem

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your are managing your data access layer and what data you need for doing the calculation? Do you have all the data you need in just one table or for each record you need to fetch some other data from another tables?

One way is to retrieve each record and do the calculation in a transaction and then store it on the database. In this way, you can also take advantage of ajax UI to inform the user about the progress of calculation. In this way, you should use SqlDataReader to fetching the data as it is very optimized and has less overhead than using DataSet and DataTables and also you can prevent several type-castings. In addition, you can also make it optimized by taking advantage of TPL or make it configurable for fetching/updating N records each time. This approach works if you have the ID of the records. You also need to have a field for your records to track your calculations in case of any disconnection or crashes or iisreset execution so that you can resume the calculation instead of rerunning it again.